# Need to know the status of a checkbox cell in a DataGridView

Tags: datagridview, checkbox

I have a C# Windows application that uses a DataGridView with three columns. The first is a textbox that requires no validation. The second and third columns are both checkboxes. I need help with determining if the boxes are checked or not. If they are then I would like to set the background color of the checkbox cell to red. I am using the DataGridView1_CellContentClick event for this. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I forgot to mention. The data is entered by the user, not from a DataSource.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
void DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  if( (bool)DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[ e.ColumnIndex].Value )
             DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[ e.ColumnIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor  = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: I need the code to determine if the box is checked or unchecked.

Comment: if the clicked cell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[ e.ColumnIndex].Value will return true if it is checked and false it it is unchecked

Comment: I get a build error on "DefaultCellStyle.BackColor". It states "'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell' does not contain a definition for 'DefaultCellStyle' ...."
I changed it to "DataGridView.BackgroundColor".
My code now compiles but I get an error on "DataGridView.BackgroundColor". It states "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index". This event is firing when the application runs before I attempt to enter a new row and before the form is even displayed.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this event fires even when you add rows to gridview by code. So if this is the case just add rows to gridview and then attach the event to the gridview

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
    bool test=false;
         test=Convert.Toboolean(DataGridView1.Rows[0].cells[0].Value);
   // if test=true then
   // its checked and if no then its unchecked.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    Try
        If e.ColumnIndex = 8 Then
            Label1.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value
            FrmVisits.Show()

        ElseIf e.ColumnIndex = 9 Then
            Label1.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value
            FrmPEdit.Show()
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Exit Sub
    End Try




End Sub
```